# Python Memory Class Object Function

Tags: python, function, class, object, memory

Why does the function "update_wts" in the following code take up memory. And why is the memory not return when function exists?

The function replaces 1 with 1 in an object variable, so why is memory added? Why is the memory not released after function exit?

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.ID = i
        self.wts = {}
        self.prc = {}
        self.numbers = []
        self.n = 1000

    def initial_values(self):
        self.numbers = range(self.n)
        for i in self.numbers:
            self.prc[i] = 1

    def update(self):
        for i in self.numbers:
            self.prc[i] = 1


how_many = 100000

classObjects = [myClass(i) for i in xrange(how_many)]

for ob in classObjects:
    ob.initial_values()

@profile
def update_wts():
    for ob in classObjects:
        ob.update()


update_wts()
```

use python -m memory_profiler test.py to see memory, place code in test.py

Comment: Your code never calls `initial_values` so it won't really do anything.

Comment: thanks. added initial_values; still uses memory